# Hive query left join get wrong result

Tags: hive, hql

First, create two tables.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;
USE test;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS student_info;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student_info(
id string COMMENT 'student id',
name string COMMENT 'student name'
)
PARTITIONED BY (l_date string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
ALTER TABLE test.student_info SET SERDEPROPERTIES('serialization.null.format' = '');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS student_score;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student_score(
id string COMMENT 'student id',
class string COMMENT 'class',
score int COMMENT 'class score'
)
PARTITIONED BY (l_date string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
ALTER TABLE test.student_score SET SERDEPROPERTIES('serialization.null.format' = '');
```

4 records in table student_info,

```
1   jobs
2   cook
3   gates
4   musk
```

3 records in table student_score,

```
1   math    98
2   math    96
3   math    94
```

I want get the student who has no score and id is '4'.

```
select * from test.student_info a
left join test.student_score b
on a.id=b.id
where (b.id='' or b.id is null)
and a.id='4';
```

and i got nothing.
but, i add the 'trim()'.

```
select * from test.student_info a
left join test.student_score b
on a.id=b.id
where (b.id='' or b.id is null)
and trim(a.id)='4';
```

i can get what i want.

```
a.id    a.name  b.id    b.class b.score
4   musk    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

so, i think there is a bug.

Comment: Hive 0.14.0
Subversion file:///Users/ghagleitner/Projects/hive-svn/rel-prep/hive-14-rel-prep -r Unknown
Compiled by ghagleitner on Sat Nov 8 23:25:06 PST 2014
From source with checksum 49c2182a0856f7917f571802a7594b0

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your data in `test.student_info` table has spaces before or after the ids. That would explain why `a.id='4'` is false while  `trim(a.id)='4'` is true.

If you load the tables from a file, check that you don't have extra spaces there.

Comment: I'm sure,there is not space.

Answer (score 0):

the best solution for that is changing the datatype of your id to int
I don't see you why put it as string when I only see integer values in your id's
 In this way you can assure that they can be compare without trimming them

Comment: It is a solution, but i just want to know why.

Comment: I changed the datatype id to int.

Comment: select * from test.student_info2 a
left join test.student_score2 b
on a.id=b.id
where (b.id='' or b.id is null)
and a.id = 4;

Comment: select * from test.student_info2 a
left join test.student_score2 b
on a.id=b.id
where (b.id='' or b.id is null)
and a.id = 4;

I can't get anything.

but ,
select * from test.student_info2 a
left join test.student_score2 b
on a.id=b.id
where (b.id='' or b.id is null);
and a.id - 4 = 0;

I can get i want.

Comment: then remove the b.id = '' condition b.id is null is enough for that alone select * from test.student_info2 a left join test.student_score2 b on a.id=b.id where b.id is null;

Answer (score 0):

As Alex stated, you must be having spaces. I tried the query you have posted on similar data rest and getting desired result.

Alternatively you can also use below query:

```
select a.id,a.name,a.l_date,b.class,b.score
FROM student_info a left join student_score b
ON a.id=b.id 
where b.score IS NULL;
```

Comment: I'm sure,there is not space.